# Multilingual admin with Globalize2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I have a multilingual admin (for English and Portuguese) that needs to save data for both languages at the same time, like Description EN field and Description PT field in the same form.

Globalize2 makes some magic and I don't know exactly how to save this. I'll post my controller action here, that obviously needs some refactoring. Thanks, people!

```
def create
  @brand = Brand.create()
  @brand.title = params[:title]
  @brand.upload_logo(params[:logo]) unless params[:logo].blank?
  @brand.order = params[:order]
  @brand.priority = params[:priority]

  plataforms = Plataform.find(:all, :conditions => ["id IN (?)", params[:plataforms]])
  @brand.plataforms = plataforms

  params[:pt].each do |k, v|
    I18n.locale = :pt
    eval "@brand.#{k} = v"
  end

  params[:en].each do |k, v|
    I18n.locale = :en
    eval "@brand.#{k} = v"  
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @brand.save
    # if 1 == 1
      flash[:notice] = 'Brand was successfully created.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@brand) }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @brand, :status => :created, :location => @brand }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @brand.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Sorry.. I've forgotten to say.. My doubt is about saving the translations. This code:

```
params[:pt].each do |k, v|
  I18n.locale = :pt
  eval "@brand.#{k} = v"
end

params[:en].each do |k, v|
  I18n.locale = :en
  eval "@brand.#{k} = v"  
end
```

Comment: I have never used globalize model translations, so I can't help you much, but using eval with user submitted data is a HUGE security risk.

Comment: I know... I'm using just to get some fields from the view with name "k" and put in a value.. for less coding... but I really don't know how to solve this in a beautiful way..

Answer (score 0):

Doing globalization using [i18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) is great and simple.

For instance :

```
flash[:notice] = t 'Brand was successfully created'
```

Then create a en.yml in config/locales :

```
en:
 Brand was successfully created: "Brand was successfully created"
```

And the portugese version as well following the same convention :

```
pt: (not sure about the country code)
Brand was successfully created: "bla bla bla I don't speak portugese"
```